# How to place two figures next to each other in itemize list

Tags: floats, indentation, itemize

How can I place two images, side-by-side, in an itemize list? I want the images to follow the indent of the itemize list, instead of page wide. I cannot figure this out.

When I have a single image (So NOT side by side), I use this code:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item FIRST ITEM \\
        RANDOM TEXT

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{IMAGE.png}
        \caption{CAPTION}
        \label{fig:IMAGE}
    \end{minipage}

\end{itemize
```

But when I want to put two images side by side I cannot use the minipage environment, and use for instance subfigures. I also cannot use a minipage within a minipage environment. How to achieve the above indent of the image, but now with two side by side images?

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item FIRST ITEM \\
        RANDOM TEXT

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{IMAGE.jpg}
            \caption{CAPTION}
            \label{fig:IMAGE}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{IMAGE.jpg}
            \caption{CAPTION2}
            \label{fig:IMAGE2}
        \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{itemize}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `\caption` macro is for use inside of a floating environment like `figure`.  However, you don't want the figure to "float" where LaTeX wants it...you want it exactly where you placed it.  So, you need to jettison the `figure` environment and replace `\caption{...}` with `\captionof{figure}{...}` which uses the `caption` package.

Answer (score 2):

As  John Kormylo said in his comment: `\linewidth` gets reset to `\textwidth` inside the `figure` float environment. Consequently, you need consider in calculation of mini pages width of `\linewidth` in list (itemize) before `figure`.

As one of possible solution is to determine new length, for example:

```
\newlength{\itemizewidth}% <-- text width in itemize
\setlength{\itemizewidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\leftmargini\relax}
```

and than consider it in `minipage`s instead of `\linewidth`:

```
\documentclass[compress,blue]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    \newlength{\itemizewidth}% <-- text width in itemize
    \setlength{\itemizewidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\leftmargini\relax}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{itemize}
\item \item some text in item before images some text in item before images some text in item befoe images
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\hfill% <-- for shift minipages to right
\begin{minipage}{0.5\itemizewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{IMAGE.jpg}
    \caption{CAPTION}
    \label{fig:IMAGE}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\itemizewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{IMAGE.jpg}
    \caption{CAPTION2}
    \label{fig:IMAGE2}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\hfill% <-- for shift minipage to right
\begin{minipage}{0.48\itemizewidth}% <-- narrowed for gap between figures
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{IMAGE.jpg}
    \caption{CAPTION}
    \label{fig:IMAGE}
\end{minipage}% 
\hspace{0.04\itemizewidth}% <-- for gap between images
\begin{minipage}{0.48\itemizewidth}% <-- narrowed for gap between figures
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{IMAGE.jpg}
    \caption{CAPTION2}
    \label{fig:IMAGE2}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

    \end{itemize}
 \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

However, the content of `figure` environment had to be moved to right border of environment. In above examples this is done by `\hfill`. First example show images with no gap between them and second with small gap (which looks more nice) obtained with `\hspace{0.04\itemizewidth}`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even with floating figures, slightly reduce 0.5\linewidth minipage to 0.45\linewidth.  Just to adjust other things around item etc.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item FIRST ITEM \\
        RANDOM TEXT
                \begin{figure}[ht]
            \centering
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{IMAGE.jpg}
                \caption{CAPTION}
                \label{fig:IMAGE}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{IMAGE.jpg}
                \caption{CAPTION2}
                \label{fig:IMAGE2}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}

        \end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't think this would work, but it does.  Note that \linewidth gets reset to \textwidth inside the figure.  OTOH, replacing \centering with \hspace{\leftmargin}% makes it look like the figure is part of the item.

Comment: You can recompute the original \linewidth using \addtolength{\linewidth}{-\leftmargin}%

Comment: It is a rough solution, just because using .5 of \linewidth twice would not accommodate two minipages.